# Checking for ForEach Odd / Even Rows

Tags: swiftui

I am working on several displays where I would like to show two portrait mode rows on the same line in landscape mode. I noticed elsewhere on [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) that the index counter is used with %2 == 1 to set the background color depending on whether the row is odd or even. I'm not having any luck getting the following to work.  The code at the odd / even check produces the error "Cannot convert value of type 'BigItem' to expected argument type 'Int'". I tried casting the counter as Int but that didn't work either.  Is there a better way to select odd or even rows?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var numbers: Numbers
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(numbers.bigItem, id: \.id) { item in
               
            if item % 2 == 0 {
                    
                Text("even")

            } else {   
                Text("odd")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your explain of issue and information about the issue is not clear and enough, try to give better perspective of issue!

Comment: When you see this elsewhere, it's because the ForEach loop is looping on an index and not an item. You can either (1) change your ForEach loop to loop on numbers.bigItem.indices or (2) create a function returned the index of the item within bigItem and use the result % 2 == 0.

Comment: What is your `Numbers` and what is `bigItem`? Would you show absent parts?

Answer (score 1):

I like using `.enumerated()` for this -- it gives you a sequence with both an index and an item back. You could use it in your example like this:

```
struct Numbers : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var bigItem : String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var numbers : [Numbers] = [Numbers(bigItem: "test"),Numbers(bigItem: "test2"),Numbers(bigItem: "test3")]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(Array(numbers.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index,item) in
            if index % 2 == 0 {
                Text("even - \(item.bigItem)")
            } else {
                Text("odd - \(item.bigItem)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way, you have access to the index to do your check on, and you still have access to the original item struct. *Note: just created a basic `Numbers` based on some guesses from your example*

Comment: Here is how the data is stored. I would like to keep this structure since it is used multiple place in my code.  Is this how others are handling landscape mode?  struct CurItem: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var cunName: String
    var curName: String
    var curCode: String
    var curSymbol: String
    var curRate: Double
}

Comment: Are you sure this comment relates to this question? I see no relationship. And I’m not sure what landscape mode has to do with it.

Comment: In landscape mode I want to display the first two portrait mode rows on the same row.  This is why I need a way to know if I'm working with odd or even rows.

Comment: If you have a different question, please ask a new question, or at least update your current one to reflect what you're asking for. In your comments, you're referring to `CurItem`, but in your example your have `Numbers`. I provided a way to tell if you're on an even or odd row. This seems to be a separate issue. If you just need to figure out what orientation you're in, I suggest you look for the SwiftUI size class environment variable: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-different-layouts-using-size-classes